# how can Python's pd.qcut give the same result as R's statar::xtile?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create bins based on one column in a dataframe. One problem is the values of that column are oddly distributed. Consequently, Python's **pd.qcut** may arbitrarily put observations into different bins, even though they have the same value.

In R (or in Stata), I use the **xtile** function of the **statar** package. R is able to group all observations with the same value into one bin.

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_df <- data.frame(customer_id  = seq(1:10),
                        purch_frequency = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 11))

sample_df <- sample_df %>% 
  mutate(freq_bins1=statar::xtile(purch_frequency, 2),
         freq_bins2=statar::xtile(purch_frequency, 3))

print(sample_df)
```

A corresponding implementation in Python,

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'customer_id': range(1,11),
        'purch_frequency': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 11]}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sample_df['freq_bins1'] = \
    (sample_df['purch_frequency'].rank(method = 'first')
     .transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels = False)))
sample_df['freq_bins2'] = \
    (sample_df['purch_frequency'].rank(method = 'first')
     .transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3, labels = False)))
print(sample_df)
```

As you can see, R and Python give different answers for the last column, freq_bins2. I wondered how I can modify the Python code so that it matches R's result. Thanks!

---

A quick follow-up. The R and Python outputs are now attached below.
For R (python's index is "1" less than R's, which is fine):

```
   customer_id purch_frequency freq_bins1 freq_bins2
1            1               1          1          1
2            2               1          1          1
3            3               1          1          1
4            4               1          1          1
5            5               1          1          1
6            6               2          2          2
7            7               3          2          2
8            8              10          2          3
9            9              11          2          3
10          10              11          2          3
```

For Python:

```
   customer_id  purch_frequency  freq_bins1  freq_bins2
0            1                1           0           0
1            2                1           0           0
2            3                1           0           0
3            4                1           0           0
4            5                1           0           1
5            6                2           1           1
6            7                3           1           1
7            8               10           1           2
8            9               11           1           2
9           10               11           1           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better answers, but I have figured out a detour by calling the R function (statar::xtile) from within Python.

```
# You need to first install rpy2
# Activate rpy2 to use R functions/packages in Python 
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
# in particular, the following two lines activate R functions
# for pandas' dataframes
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri 
pandas2ri.activate()

### This chunk is the same as the original post
import pandas as pd
data = {'customer_id': range(1,11),
        'purch_frequency': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 11]}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sample_df['freq_bins1'] = \
    (sample_df['purch_frequency'].rank(method = 'first')
     .transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 2, labels = False)))
sample_df['freq_bins2'] = \
    (sample_df['purch_frequency'].rank(method = 'first')
     .transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3, labels = False)))

### The following is to call R's statar::xtile
statar = importr('statar')
sample_df['freq_bin3'] = statar.xtile(sample_df['purch_frequency'], 3)

print(sample_df)
```

The output looks like the following:

```
   customer_id  purch_frequency  freq_bins1  freq_bins2  freq_bin3
0            1                1           0           0          1
1            2                1           0           0          1
2            3                1           0           0          1
3            4                1           0           0          1
4            5                1           0           1          1
5            6                2           1           1          2
6            7                3           1           1          2
7            8               10           1           2          3
8            9               11           1           2          3
9           10               11           1           2          3
```